# Why cant open itms-services protocol inside an UIWebView iOS7.1 app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I open an UIWebView with the following link:

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://XXX.plist

The server it's SSL (https) enabled. If I open the page in Safari works right and I can download and install the update, but when I open the equal link inside the App y press the link and nothings happen.

Edit:

Console: Navigation started when state=1

Comment: Have you implemented all necessary delegate methods?

Comment: Console: <Warning>: webView:didFailLoadWithError - CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

App has to hadle custom schemes by its own. Catch URL in `UIWebViewDelegate` and open it by  `UIApplication` (if it can handle it):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    if (!([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"] || [url.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"] || [url.scheme isEqualToString:@"about"])) {
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if ([app canOpenURL:url]) [app openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: console: <Warning>: webView:didFailLoadWithError - CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1

Comment: To update app just open such link using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-service://....."]];` - in case of enterprise/ad-hoc app user will be asked if he wants to install it (if only link and manifest are ok), itunes links will open AppStore app. Anyway in both cases user can not allow for update and you cannot prevent it.

Comment: That warning above does not look like something related to opening custom schemes inside app / web view.

Answer (score 2):

To update app just open such link using
 `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-service://....."]];`